# Asterisk + MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, asterisk

Доброго времени суток всем. Подскажите, какие могут возникнуть проблемы при переходе с MySQL на MariaDB при работе с астериском? А то в силу оптимизации работы системы, рассматриваем переход с MySQL на MariaDB, но от корректности работы с астером многое зависит.

**Обновление**

Тут не столько проблема, сколько вопрос в надежде, что кто-то уже сталкивался с подобной ситуацией. А именно: существует и работает связка asterisk 11:12.2 и MySQL-сервер версии 5.5.38. Хотим перейти на MariaDB для ускорения работы системы. И вот вопрос, насколько MariaDB поддерживает связь с asterisk, поскольку на одном из форумов видел старое сообщение, что была проблема с поддержкой odbc в MariaDB. Вот соответственно, вопрос, столкнемся ли мы с возможными проблемами при попытке перехода. Потому что простой у нас, к сожалению, недопустим.

Comment: Сори, не указал версию астера - 1:11.12

Comment: совершенно не ясно, каким образом тут всплыл odbc. у вас что, *ms/windows* используется? тогда, наверно, возможны любые глюки. даже без смены версии субд.

Answer (score 1):

Уже совсем скоро функция диалплана MySQL(...) станет deprecated и основным механизмом взаимодействия с ..SQL станет (да что греха таить - уже стал) ODBC, который реализован на func_odbc.conf (именнованные функциями запросы из диалплана с передачей аргументов и значений) и res_odbc.conf - описывается коннектор ODBC используемый для доступа к конкретной БД (odbc.ini и odbcinst.ini лежат обычно в /etc/). Так что ODBC - это не к WINDOWS... Топикстартер прав. 
Разница между ними, безусловно есть. Нужно внимательно смотреть запросы, но с большой долей вероятности скажу что разработчики рассчитывали на совместимость.